# Any Steps to perform standard partition disk to LVM disk conversion, without data loss

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm

I have Data disk and data disk type is Standard Partition and We are Planning to convert that data disk from standard partition to LVM disk partition, but data loss should not happen, Any One have Steps Please update here.**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to convert disk partition to PV (for the purpose of build LVM). What you can do is to use some shared storage/removable disk to temporary copy the existing information.

You can check also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/241998/293588).